# Java how to increase font size?

Tags: java, fonts

Hello I have this code which creates a font from a ttf file in my res folder.

```
         try {
            font1 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/1942.ttf"));
            font1.deriveFont(12f);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I thought `.deriveFont();` increased the custom font size but for me it dosnt. What is wrong?
Here is where is use the font.

```
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        font1.deriveFont(52);
        g.setFont(font1);

        g.drawString("hello",480, 250);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `font1.deriveFont(12f);` doesn't change font1. Rather it **returns** a new Font of differing size. You need to something with this returned object, perhaps something like:

```
setFont(font1.deriveFont(12f));
```

or

```
font1 = font1.deriveFont(12f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

you can use another approach also

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setFont(btn.getFont().deriveFont(14.0f));
```